# Why not logistic regression uses multiplication instead of addition for error matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

This is a very basic question but I cannot could not find enough reasons to convince myself. Why must logistic regression use multiplication instead of addition for the likelihood function l(w)?

Comment: What do you mean by "use multiplication instead of addition"? When does logistic regression "use" multiplication?

Comment: @ilanman, the likelihood function is a multiplication of the likelihood of all data points, right? so my question is, why cannot use the addition(summation) here as a measurement of how well the result is.

Comment: When data is i.i.d, then the joint likelihood is a product of the probabilities for each sample. This is true for all cases (not just logistic regression). However if you take the log of the probabilities, then you can add them up. It's quite common to take the log of the likelihood for this purpose

Comment: @ilanman, so it is not wrong to use the sum. just not common?

Comment: Using the sum of log probabilities is very common. If you look up maximum likelihood estimation for most parameters, you'll see some sort of log transform, and then summation

Comment: @ilanman, not after log transformation. I understand that multiplication is converted to addition after log transformation. I wonder if it is reasonable to use the sum of probabilities, not log probabilities, to represent joint likelihood. I have never seen people doing so; at the same time, never see someone says it is wrong to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more general than just joint likelihood for logistic regression. You're asking why we multiply probabilities instead of add them to represent a joint probability distribution. Two notes:

1. This applies when we assume random variables are independent. Otherwise we need to calculate conditional probabilities using the chain rule of probability. You can look at wikipedia for more information.
2. We multiply because that's how the joint distribution is defined. Here is a simple example:

Say we have two probability distributions:

```
X = 1, 2, 3,  each with probability 1/3
Y = 0 or 1,  each with probability 1/2
```

We want to calculate the joint likelihood function, `L(X=x,Y=y)`, which is that `X` takes on values `x` and `Y` takes on values `y`.

For example, `L(X=1,Y=0) = P(X=1) * P(Y=0) = 1/6`. It wouldn't make sense to write `P(X=1) + P(Y=0) = 1/3 + 1/2 = 5/6`.

Now it's true that in maximum likelihood estimation, we only care about those values of some parameter, theta, which maximizes the likelihood function. In this case, we know that if theta maximizes `L(X=x,Y=y)` then the same theta will also maximize `log L(X=x,Y=y)`. This is where you may have seen addition of probabilities come into play.

Hence we can take the `log P(X=x,Y=y) = log P(X=x) + log P(Y=y)`

**In short**

This could be summarized as "joint probabilities represent an AND". When `X` and `Y` are independent, `P(X AND Y) = P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y)`. Not to be confused with `P(X OR Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X,Y)`.

Let me know if this helps.